# Show that $\kappa(Q_n) =\lambda (Q_n)=n$ all positive integer $n$

Tags: graph-theory

Show that $\kappa(Q_n) =\lambda (Q_n)=n$ all positive integer $n$

I want to prove this by induction. so I start with $n=1$

Base: $n=1$ then $Q_1=K_2$, which have $\kappa(Q_1) =\lambda (Q_1)=1$. So the base is good.

Inductive step:

Assume that this work for $n=k$, meaning for $Q_k = K_2 \times K_2 \times \dots \times K_2$, $k$ times, $\kappa(Q_k) =\lambda (Q_k)=k$. I need to show that it work for $n=k+1$. I know that $Q_{k+1} = K_2 \times K_2 \times \dots \times K_2$, $k+1$ times, so $Q_{k+1}$ has $2^{k+1}$ vertices and we obtain $Q_{k+1}$ by taking 2 copies of $Q_k$ and connect their vertices pairwise, so there must be at least $k+1$ bridges. In each bridge, there must be at least one cut vertices, so  there are at least $k+1$ cut vertices in $Q_{k+1}$, So  $\kappa(Q_{k+1}) =\lambda (Q_{k+1})=k+1$

On inductive step, I don't feel like I explain it clear enough. I would be appreciate if anyone help me improve it.

Comment: How is $\lambda$ defined? And hypercubes (apart from $Q_1$) have no bridges at all, so what is your definition of a bridge?

Comment: $\lambda$ is the size of edge cut $X$, maybe I used the wrong word, I need to cut many edges to get the graph disconnected, so I can't call any edge the bridge :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the induction step needs a bit of work. Assuming that you know the result that $\kappa(G)\le\lambda(G)$ for all graphs $G$, you can simplify the overall argument a bit: you need only show that $\kappa(Q_n)\ge n$ and $\lambda(Q_n)\le n$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. The latter is pretty easy and doesn’t need induction; can you see how to remove $n$ edges from $Q_n$ to disconnect it?

For the other inequality, prove by induction on $n$ that if $u$ and $v$ are distinct vertices of $Q_n$, there are at least $n$ paths from $u$ to $v$ such that if $P_0$ and $P_1$ are any two of these paths, $u$ and $v$ are the only vertices that are on both $P_0$ and $P_1$. Suppose that you’ve proved that. Then removing fewer than $n$ vertices from $Q_n$ must leave a connected graph, because if $u$ and $v$ are any two of the remaining vertices, there is a path from $u$ to $v$ in $Q_n$ that does not include any of the removed vertices.

It helps to label the vertices of $K_2$ as $0$ and $1$; since $Q_n$ is the product of $n$ copies of $K_2$, its vertices correspond to $n$-tuples of $0$s and $1$s, and two vertices are adjacent in $Q_n$ if and only if they differ in exactly one coordinate. Suppose that there are at least $n$ disjoint paths between any two vertices of $Q_n$, and consider distinct vertices $u=\langle u_1,\ldots,u_{n+1}\rangle$ and $v=\langle v_1,\ldots,v_{n+1}\rangle$ in $Q_{n+1}$. Suppose that there is some $k$ such that $u_k=v_k$. Let $u'=\langle u_1,\ldots,u_{k-1},u_{k+1},\ldots,u_{n+1}\rangle$ be obtained from $u$ by deleting the $k$-th coordinate, and similarly let $v'=\langle v_1,\ldots,v_{k-1},v_{k+1},\ldots,v_{n+1}\rangle$; these are distinct vertices in $Q_n$, so there are $n$ disjoint paths between them in $Q_n$.

- Show how to turn these $n$ paths into disjoint paths from $u$ to $v$ in $Q_{n+1}$. HINT: What should the $k$-th coordinate of each vertex on these paths be?
- Find one more path from $u$ to $v$ in $Q_{n+1}$. HINT: the first vertex after $u$ should be $\langle u_1,\ldots,u_{k-1},?,u_{k+1},\ldots,u_{n+1}\rangle$.

There remains the possibility that $u$ and $v$ differ in *every* coordinate. You might as well assume for simplicity that they are $\langle 0,\ldots,0\rangle$ and $\langle 1,\ldots,1\rangle$, since you can always rearrange the labelling of the factors $K_2$ to make this true.

- Find $n+1$ disjoint paths from $\langle\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{n+1}\rangle$ to $\langle\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{n+1}\rangle$.

Comment: I know that $Q_n = Q_{n-1} \times K_2$ so in order to get $Q_n$ disconnected, I need to remove $n-1$ edge. Is this argument enough to show that $\lambda (Q_n) \leq n$?

Comment: @Diane: You don’t need induction for this inequality. Pick one vertex of $Q_n$; how many edges do you have to remove to isolate that one vertex from the rest of $Q_n$?

Comment: $Q_n$ have $2^{n}$ vertices, so if I wan to disconnect completely one vertex from another component of $Q_n$ then I need to remove $n$ edges?

Comment: @Diane: The number of vertices of $Q_n$ is irrelevant. If $v$ is a vertex of $Q_n$, what is $\deg(v)$? That’s the number of edges that meet at $v$, and if you remove all of them, ...

Comment: I see, every vertex in $Q_n$ has degree $n$, so I still need to remove that many edges to get an isolated vertex. I will try working on the second parts and see if I can understand it.

Comment: @Diane: That’s right: removing the $n$ edges at a vertex disconnects that vertex from the rest of the graph, so $\lambda(Q_n)$ cannot be more than $n$.